# In android, why does Local variable which is not declared by final work at ClickListener?

Tags: android, final

In following code, why does local variable which is not declared final work in the ClickListener??
Local variables without final are destroyed at the end of the `onCreate` method, so it shouldn't be accessible in the `OnClickListener`, right?
But, in the following code the value of `a` is shown in the Toast. I don't understand why...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String a = "a";

        Button btnMinus = findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);

        btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is ***effectively final***.

But if you add

```
String a = "";
a = "a";
```

and leave the rest of your code unchanged, then it will fail to compile as it wont be *effectively final* anymore.